# Optional conversion from Guava to Java

Tags: java, guava, option-type

How to make conversion from Guava Optional to Java Optional, without usage of any if statements?

```
if (maybeSomething.isPresent()) {
    return java.util.Optional.of(maybeSomething.get())
} else {
    return java.util.Optional.empty()
}
```

Comment: More contextual information is needed; does your code base use Guava's Optional extensively? How do you plan to replace it with Java 8's? How do you use Guava's Optional currently? Will you expect usages of existing instances in, for instance, Stream's .findAny()? You need a migration strategy first and foremost

Comment: How would you do it with an if statement? Have you tried anything?

Comment: no general problem with api migration, just have single case where i need such conversion

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use guava transformation

```
maybeSomething
    .transform(java.util.Optional::of).or(java.util.Optional.empty());
```

Comment: Seeing no obvious technical reason to choose between this and @Kayaman's null-based approach, I was curious whether one or the other would show a performance advantage. I whipped up some quick performance tests, and found no significant difference in execution times. Further analysis shows significantly more (~2x) object allocations for the null-based approach. So, I think this answer is definitely the most correct.

Answer (score 25):

[Guava Release 21](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release21) introduced the [`toJavaUtil`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#toJavaUtil--) and [`fromJavaUtil`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#fromJavaUtil-java.util.Optional-) conversion methods to the [`Optional`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) class.

```
javaUtilOptional = Optional.toJavaUtil(guavaOptional);
guavaOptional    = Optional.fromJavaUtil(javaUtilOptional);
```

Under the hood it seems to be implemented largely as the suggestion in Kayaman's answer:

```
public java.util.Optional<T> toJavaUtil() {
    return java.util.Optional.ofNullable(orNull());
}

...

public static <T> Optional<T> fromJavaUtil(@Nullable java.util.Optional<T> javaUtilOptional) {
    return (javaUtilOptional == null) ? null : fromNullable(javaUtilOptional.orElse(null));
}
```

Answer (score 15):

How about `Optional javaOpt = Optional.ofNullable(guavaOpt.orNull());`?

Comment: This requires conversion to null and back, but with optional usually you want to work with nulles

Comment: True, but since there's no downside in converting to null, this provides a shorter way to get the exact same end result.

Comment: See my comment on @MariuszS's answer -- this option performs more object allocations. If you're dealing with any significant volume of calls, the alternative answer, while slightly longer (put it in a utility method and never look at it again), will reduce strain on the garbage collector.

Comment: I don't care how old a question is. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: And as for "real" questions, I use this site for work. I'm not just trolling SO for questions to answer (nothing wrong with that -- just not something I generally have time for). When I have a need, I often check SO. If I don't find what I'm looking for, I contribute by figuring it out and commenting or answering accordingly.

Comment: I did some analysis, and commented with my findings. Why do you feel the need to be rude about it?

Comment: Release 21 of Guava contains built-in functionality for convertering between `java.util.Optional` and Guava's `Optional`. They seem to have gone for this approach. https://github.com/google/guava/blob/d9f088a61c80fa47d09ccf05a8c3608a47c5e4c0/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Optional.java#L129

Comment: @Henrik You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on the usages you currently do of your Guava's Optionals; and the first problem lies with the differences between both.

Among others:

- Guava's Optional is abstract, Java 8's is final;
- methods exist on Guava's which do not on Java 8's, and vice versa.

Which means the first thing you need to determine is your different usages of Guava's; this will condition the way you'll have to build an equivalent Java 8's.

But given the difference in API for both, some `if`s along the way seem unavoidable...

My personal suggestion here would be to just go all the way and replace all current uses of Guava's with Java 8's; and if a "phaseout period" is needed, deprecate the necessary methods and provide them as long as needed, until Guava's Optional is ruled out entirely.

Comment: it wasn't me who downvoted, but you seem to not really address the question, but rather give a nice overview of the pros, cons and differences between the two available `Optional`-implementations.